# Maximum call stack exceeded on recursion function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to make a function that iterates over and over until there is nothing left to iterate.
The function is supposed to: grab index of beginning of each container, grab the index of where the next comma is (this would then be a whole container ---- (ex: APZU09342342 Y257), add that to array, make the new string the same old string but without that extracted part, etc all the way till the end. The array is supposed to have each of these extracted parts as an index/item. But the problem is I am getting "Maximum call stack exceeded" Here is my function:

```
let string = `ACCU2083917   C324
ACSU2051784 J178
AMFU3002084 Z978
AMFU3153780 
AMFU8735314 Z952
AMFU8817182 C324
AMFU8817201 W185
AMFU8923287 Y258
ANYU2097165 
APHU6365825 Y257
APHU6392501 E364
APHU6416096 E364
APHU6492265 WAC8
APHU6496430 J745
`;

let reg_newline = /\n/gi;  //       ---- USE THIS
string = string.replace(reg_newline, ",\n");

let endIndex = string.indexOf(',');

let carryContainers = [];

let cutString;
Iterate();
function Iterate() {
    // take out the container + terminal part
    cutString = string.substring(0, endIndex);
    // push the container + terminal part in array
    carryContainers.push(cutString);

    // make string start after the comma for every iteration
    string = string.substring(endIndex + 1, string.length)
    // make end index of next container 
    endIndex = string.indexOf(',');
    //console.log(endIndex)
    if (endIndex) {
        Iterate();
    }

    if (!endIndex) {
        console.log(carryContainers);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `if (endIndex)` to do?

Comment: The `.indexOf()` function returns a *number*, not a boolean, and in particular it will be `-1` when the comma is not found. The number -1 is `true` when tested as a boolean.

Comment: if (endIndex) is supposed to mean that if there is still a comma found, execute the function again. -1 is true? I thought it was false, which is what my if (!endIndex) is supposed to read as false?

Comment: Only `0` is falsy, any other number is truthy.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem.